# Running a webserver on the same server as an OpenVPN setup

Tags: networking, vpn, webserver, openvpn

I have an application which runs as a web server. An absolutely regular type of server.

But, the application needs to connect to another server through a VPN.
If I run an OpenVPN client on my server machine, will my web server still work fine? Or is there something I can do to route my web apps request through the OpenVPN client and keep the web traffic flowing normally (not through OpenVPN)?

---

For example, one thing I’m worried about is if someone connects to my server (for example `1.1.1.1`), they will get a response from my VPN ip (`4.4.4.4`). Or a myriad of other possible problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `web server` can connect as a client to a VPN without effecting the `web server` basic function.
2. If the `web client` connecting to your `web server` is configured with
   appropriate routing (ie: the client *knows* that the web server has
   another IP 4.4.4.4) then the client can probe the server to *try*
   connecting to 4.4.4.4 - Typically, you would use your `server
   firewall` to block such attempts.
3. > myriad of other possible problems

   Please be specific.

Comment: Thank you for the response. By 3 I meant that I don't know what other problems can occur.

Comment: So if someone connects to my server by GETting 1.1.1.1, they will receive a response from 1.1.1.1, even if I'm running a OpenVPN client that is connected to 4.4.4.4?

Comment: The reply will come from `1.1.1.1` .  If your `web server` also uses a VPN to connect to a service required by the `web server`, like a non-local database, this should never reply to the client as the `web client` is **only** connected to the `web server`. The VPN IP and the client cannot see each other.